# map is loaded as it is clicked

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback{
  private MapView mymapv;
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    buildGoogleApiClient();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    mymapv=(MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mymapv.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mymapv.getMapAsync(this);
    ...
    }
   @Override
     public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
   .position(new LatLng(-24.25659,-65.21643))
   .title("Marker"));
   map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
   }
}
```

and xml is

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:clickable="true"
    map:cameraZoom="14"
    map:uiCompass="true"
    map:uiZoomControls="true" />
```

That xml is part of a FrameLayout.
I think nothing is incorrect. But when the app is tested in a real phone with Android 4.4.2, the map is first showed as grey grid, if I rotate the phone or touch the screen, the map starts the rendering by sectors. Also, I can't drag the map to another place directly, except if I do click on the map it starts to move. Zoom in or out is done after I click the map. I don't know what is going on. LogCat doesn't report errors :-/
I didn't test it in other devices or Android versions.

Comment: may I know why the -1 ?

Comment: You can try clone my repo [here](https://github.com/jbj88817/GoogleMap-basic-android) to set up the map, I tired and it worked. Also in your `xml`, use the `SupportMapFragment` instead of `Mapview`.